# Tokenization by Stanford parser is slow?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, stanford-nlp

Quession Summary: tokenization by stanford parser is slow on my local machine, but unreasonably much much faster on spark. Why?

---

I'm using stanford coreNLP tool to tokenize sentences.

My script in Scala is like this:

```
import java.util.Properties
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._ 
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap
import scala.io.Source

import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
val properties = new Properties()
val coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties)

def tokenize(s: String)  = { 
  properties.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize")
  val annotation = new Annotation(s)
  coreNLP.annotate(annotation)
  annotation.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation]).map(_.value.toString)
}

tokenize("Here is my sentence.")
```

One call of `tokenize` function takes roughly (at least) 0.1 sec.
This is very very slow because I have 3 million sentences.
(3M * 0.1sec = 300K sec = 5000H)

---

As an alternative approach, I have applied the tokenizer on Spark.
(with four worker machines.)

```
import java.util.List
import java.util.Properties
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._  
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP

val file = sc.textFile("hdfs:///myfiles")

def tokenize(s: String)  = { 
  val properties = new Properties()
  properties.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize")
  val coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties)
  val annotation = new Annotation(s)
  coreNLP.annotate(annotation)
  annotation.get(classOf[TokensAnnotation]).map(_.toString)
}

def normalizeToken(t: String) = {
  val ts = t.toLowerCase
  val num = "[0-9]+[,0-9]*".r
  ts match {
    case num() => "NUMBER"
    case _ => ts
  }
}

val tokens = file.map(tokenize(_))
val tokenList = tokens.flatMap(_.map(normalizeToken))
val wordCount = tokenList.map((_,1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).sortBy(_._2, false)
wordCount.saveAsTextFile("wordcount")
```

This scripts finishes tokenization and word count of 3 million sentences just in **5 minites**!
And results seems reasonable.
Why this is so first? Or, why the first scala script is so slow?

Comment: You can use Stanford NLP simple API on Spark which is much faster compare to CoreNLP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first approach is that you set the `annotators` property after you initialize the `StanfordCoreNLP` object. Therefore CoreNLP is initialized with the list of default annotators which include the part-of-speech tagger and the parser which are orders of magnitude slower than the tokenizer.

To fix this, simply move the line

```
properties.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize")
```

before the line

```
val coreNLP = new StanfordCoreNLP(properties)
```

This should be even slightly faster than your second approach as you don't have to reinitialize CoreNLP for each sentence.